# Prove $\overline{(A \times (B \cap C))} = \overline{(A \times B)} \cup \overline{(A \times C)}$, for any sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ over universe set $U$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $\overline{(A \times (B \cap C))} = \overline{(A \times B)} \cup \overline{(A \times C)}$, for any sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ over universe set $U$. 
 I need to specifically use logic laws rather than distributive laws for sets, or de Morgan’s laws for sets, and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Did you mean $A\times(B\cap C)=(A\times B)\cap(A\times C)$, or perhaps $A\times(B\cup C)=(A\times B)\cup(A\times C)$? Either way, a hint: when is $(x,\,y)$ an element of each side?

Comment: sorry I corrected it as best as I can, both elements are meant to be ¬ however I'm unsure how to correctly notate that here

Comment: I edited your notation as the picture you uploaded, but I think $A^c$ is more common notation for the complementary set of $A$. Therefore, I think you need to explain your notations explicitely here.

Comment: Ohhh!!!  And entire change of the problem!!!!   (Very annoying...)

Comment: really sorry about that, I'm new to MathJax notation. and thanks for the edit jingeon

Answer (score 2):

Since $\overline{\overline{X}\cup\overline{Y}}=X\cap Y$ and $\overline{X}=\overline{Y}\iff X=Y$, this is equivalent to proving $A\times(B\cap C)=(A\times B)\cap(A\times C)$, which I'll leave you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times(B\cap C)}$, then either $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B\cap C$. In the former case, $(x,y)\notin A\times B$, hence $(x,y)\in\overline{A\times B}\subset \overline{A\times B}\cup\overline{A\times C}$. For the later case, either $y\notin B$ or $y\notin C$, so suppose $y\notin B$ without loosing generality, then $(x,y)\notin A\times B$, hence $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times B}\cup\overline{A\times C}$. Therefore $\overline{A\times(B\cap C)}\subset \overline{A\times B}\cup\overline{A\times C}$.

For the opposite side, take any $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times B}$. Then $(x,y)\notin A\times B$, hence either $x\notin A$, or $y\notin B$. In the former case, $(x,y)\notin A\times(B\cap C)$, hence $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times(B\cap C)}$. For the later case, $y\notin B\cap C$, hence $(x,y)\notin A\times (B\cap C)$, leading to $(x,y)\in \overline{A\times (B\cap C)}$. Therefore $\overline{A\times B}\subset \overline{A\times (B\cap C)}$. Same result holds for $\overline{A\times C}$, we have $\overline{A\times B}\cup\overline{A\times C}\subset \overline{A\times (B\cap C)}$.

Therefore two sets are equal.

And of course it is easier to show $A\times (B\cap C)=(A\times B)\cap (B\times C)$, but as you wanted, I did not used any set operation laws.

Comment: thanks for the response, however according to the question we can't use for example $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$ but must use the equivalent logic laws instead

Comment: @Statik I did not use De morgan's law on the proof.

Comment: sorry, I'm not explaining it well. the question just specifies that rather than my example in the above comment we must use eg {x | ¬(x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ B)} or {x | ¬(x ∈ A) ∧ ¬(x ∈ B)}

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the proof.. Just different notations.